# Cambiar error required (campo en blanco)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap

¿Cuál es la forma más sencilla para que, si no se elige un valor de un select y se envía el formulario, cambie el color del fondo del select además de mostrar el mensaje de error?

Gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Creo que pude solucionar tu problema , mira  mi respuesta a ver que te parce . @Paco S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lo que necesitas es darle valor a tus `option` entonces dejas la primera opcion como por defecto y le dejas el `value=""` de manera que asi no tenga valor el `select` por defecto y asi el `require` ara su efecto .

Para poner el background a rojo solo has de añadir una classe a tu archivo `css` para especificar `:focus:required:invalid`

Te dejo aqui un ejemplo para que puedas verlo mejor

```css
select:focus:required:invalid {
  background-color: #f9bfbe;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<form  class="form-horizontal" action="#" method="post">
  <select  class="selectpicker form-control" required>
    <option value="">Selecciona una opcion</option>
    <option value="q">001</option>
    <option value="q">002</option>
    <option value="q" >003</option>
  </select>
  
  <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar JavaScript para hacer este proceso de esta forma.

```js
let variable;

variable = document.getElementById('tuID').value

if (variable === '') {
    variable.focus();
    document.getElementById('tuID').style.background = '#000' // COLOR DE FONDO QUE NESECITES 
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="variable" id="variable" aria-required="true" required />
```